# Aptana Studio 3 - Syntax highlighting for Handlebars files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, aptana, aptana3, handlebars.js

How do I get Aptana to apply the same syntax highlighting and auto-complete that exists on .html files to my files that end in .handlebars?

I'm assuming there must be some setting in Preferences to allow this, but I'm not seeing it.

If it helps, I'm using version 3.0.7.2011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, recently figured this one out.

Under **Windows > Preferences** select **General > Editors > File Associations**.

Here, you can simple add whatever extension you want, then the editor that you want to apply it to.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

After you click "Ok" you will have whatever syntax highlighting or code completion that the editor you specified has.